# Changing SVN externals via a script?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'd like to change SVN externals via a simple script after I do branching (also via script). My externals are pointing to "trunk" and after I branch they should point to "branches/release/1.0" for example.

Is there a way of editing SVN externals via a script?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
svn propset svn:externals 'extern_dir https://example.org/svn/trunk/some/path' .
```

If you need to have multiple extern directories, split it with new line char.

Comment: Thanks. Can I do it directly on server, instead of having to checkout first?

Comment: Think, no, because this operation will cause working copy modification (changed property of directory) and need to be commited using `svn ci -m ...'.

Comment: loentar is right. You cannot change a svn property without a working copy